# In BLE, who decides which pairing mode is to be used? Peripheral/Central

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I've been looking for BLE materials to get answer to this. But I could not get in any. Though practically/logically speaking, peripheral should decide I want to see if it is documented some where. Any links with this information will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, at least, if the peripheral specifies that encryption is required for a characteristic then iOS Central will initiate a pairing operation when access is attempted.  If encryption isn't required then no pairing takes place - The central can just initiate a connection.

So, in summary -

- The peripheral 'decides' if pairing is required through the definition of its characteristics.
- The central manages the pairing process when required.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: Pairing can be established using Just Works, Passkey or OOB mechanisms as per BLE spec. But the BLE sample apps acting as peripheral (Attack pattern etc) always asks for pin entry (Passkey). Can this avoided and paired using just works?

Comment: iOS only pairs if encryption is required, in which case it uses a passkey.  If encryption isn't required then you can just connect (which is I presume what is meant by 'just works') but it isn't a permanent pairing as such. In iOS a pairing results in the peripheral appearing the Bluetooth settings even when it isn't connected and the storage of encryption keys.  BLE devices that aren't paired using a passkey are visible in the settings app while they are connected, but not when they aren't

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarifying my doubts

Answer (score 0):

On "Just Works"; my understanding is that this is pairing where neither device can display a passkey, or allow the user to input one. It is NOT an unencrypted connections.

While your general iOS device can do both, many devices, such as an toothbrush handle, can't, but can still require "just works" pairing and bounding. This is also called unauthenticated pairing with encryption. It appears that iOS will prompt the user to accept a pairing request if the peripheral can't display a passkey.